# SQL Server 2005 HTTP Endpoint Authentication

Tags: sql, web-services, sql-server-2005

Is there any way of setting up an endpoint that does not require Integrated Authentication or HTTPS - either basic username / password authenticaion or none at all???

Comment: I dont want integrated authentication - I just want to be able to supply a username and password and be done with it. Or nothing at all, its just lets me call it with no authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can either have integrated authentication over HTTP, or SQL Server authentication over HTTPS.

If you want anonymous authorisation, you need to write your own web service wrapper for the database calls. This is probably a good idea anyway, since native SOAP endpoints are deprecated in SQL 2008.